# How to await for async database call to resolve before proceeding with function to alter the DOM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm trying to dynamically add elements to a Table, kind of like a ledger. I have a few HTML buttons. The buttons are loaded to the DOM dynamically from a MongoDB collection. I am using NodeJS, using PUG/Jade as the view engine, and I'm putting the _id values from the DB as the id values of each button. This way I can query the DB for other properties with an onclick function.

Each time I click a button, I run a fetch call to my backend get the price property stored in the MongoDB:

```
function getPriceFromDatabase() {
var target = event.target;
var id = target.id;
var url = '/menus/' + id;

fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function(res){
    if(!res.ok) console.log("Error");
    else return res.json().then(function(result){
        var returnedItem = JSON.parse(result)
        console.log("Item Price: " + returnedItem[0].itemPrice);
        return returnedItem[0].itemPrice;
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
}
```

This works fine.

My problem is when I try to call this function to add new rows to a table.

```
function createTableElement () {
var newTableRow = document.createElement("tr");

var target = event.target;

var nameCell = document.createElement("td");
var nameText = document.createTextNode(target.textContent);

nameCell.appendChild(nameText);
newTableRow.appendChild(nameCell);

var priceOfItem = getPriceFromDatabase()

var priceCell = document.createElement("td");
var priceText = document.createTextNode(priceOfItem);

priceCell.appendChild(priceText);
newTableRow.appendChild(priceCell);

ledgerTable.appendChild(newTableRow);
}
```

The function runs without waiting for the result of getPriceFromDatabase()

This means that I get a table where the first column correctly states the name of the button which was clicked, but the price column is undefined. It simply takes some time for the database to be queried and return a value, and by the time it happens the function which calls the query has already completed.

What are my options? I'm still a novice to using promises and asynchronous functions. I understand that fetch returns a promise as a response object, which is why I can use .then()

I have tried changing my DOM-table function to something like:

```
getPriceFromDatabase().then( [construct the rest of the table elements] )
```

This is invalid since .then() is not a property of that function, since it doesn't return a promise. What can I do?

I have tried doing

async getPriceFromDatabase() {}, but it still gives me an error that I can't use .then()

How can I solve this? Do I have to use new Promise ()? I would appreciate if someone could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPriceFromDatabase()` is an asynchronous function.  You need to return the promise from it and use `.then()` on that returned promise:

```
function getPriceFromDatabase() {
    var target = event.target;
    var id = target.id;
    var url = '/menus/' + id;

    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(res){
        if(!res.ok) console.log("Error");
        else return res.json().then(function(result){
            var returnedItem = JSON.parse(result)
            console.log("Item Price: " + returnedItem[0].itemPrice);
            return returnedItem[0].itemPrice;
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });
    });
}


function createTableElement () {
    var newTableRow = document.createElement("tr");

    var target = event.target;

    var nameCell = document.createElement("td");
    var nameText = document.createTextNode(target.textContent);

    nameCell.appendChild(nameText);
    newTableRow.appendChild(nameCell);

    getPriceFromDatabase().then(function(priceOfItem) {

        var priceCell = document.createElement("td");
        var priceText = document.createTextNode(priceOfItem);

        priceCell.appendChild(priceText);
        newTableRow.appendChild(priceCell);

        ledgerTable.appendChild(newTableRow);
    });
}
```

Summary of changes:

1. `fetch(url)` was changed to `return fetch(url)`, thus returning the promise.
2. `var priceOfItem = getPriceFromDatabase()` is changed to `getPriceFromDatabase.then(...)`.

Also, you really should be passing the `event` into both functions rather than relying on a global.

---

> I have tried changing my DOM-table function to something like: `getPriceFromDatabase().then( [construct the rest of the table elements] )`.

That didn't work for you because you did not return the promise from `getPriceFromDatabase()` so therefore there was no `.then()` handler on the return value.

> I tried `async getPriceFromDatabase() {}`, but it still gives me an error that I can't use `.then()`

Same issue.  You still have to return the promise.

Comment: Extremely helpful answer. Can you elaborate on what you mean about globals? I thought that these variables were local and would disappear after the onClick functions run. Did you mean that I should simply use 'return fetch(event.target.id)' as opposed to declaring them before the fetch call? Or am I missing the what you are trying to tell me?                            Also, I did not know that I could should return fetch like that. So, fetch itself is a promise, and contains a promise within that is a response object? Or is return fetch(...) a means of returning the response object itself?

Comment: @Mikhail - `fetch()` returns a promise.  So, when you do `return fetch()`, you're returning a promise from the host function.  What I meant about `event` is that you aren't passing that INTO any of your functions so you are apparently using the global `event` object.  That's NOT a good thing to do in asynchronous functions as the global `event` can change before you use it.  You should pass the event into `createTableElement(event)` and then again pass it into `getPriceFromDatabase(event)`.  Actually, `getPriceFromDatabase()` would be more generally useful if you passed in the `id` instead.

Comment: Understood. I had not considered the event changing since most of my calls are relatively quick at this point. I followed your advice and changed my onClick functions to `createTableElement(this.id)`. Passing that through the function chain basically removed the need for using the event object. Thanks again for the tips.